# Delete Firestore Collection Using Dataflow & Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, pipeline, dataflow

I have a function in Java which is reading the data from firestore collection and deleting them with fixed batch size.
I want to execute this from dataflow, but when I add this in .apply I am getting compilation error:
"The method apply(String, PTransform) in the type Pipeline is not applicable for the arguments (String, void)"

How can we call such a function inside apply

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to perhaps provide a code sample along with a stack trace detailing your error? This will help in better visualizing what you may be trying to achieve.

This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data#collections) provides details on deleting entire collections or subcollections in Cloud Firestore. If you are using a larger collection, you have the option to delete data in smaller batches to avoid out-of-memory errors. The [code snippet](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/e589c8f6c86596f60188c3afc8a576263cc45c6f/firestore/src/main/java/com/example/firestore/snippets/ManageDataSnippets.java#L310-L331) is somewhat simplified, but provides a method on deleting a collection in batches.